# Magnolia Page Template not registering

Tags: magnolia

I watched a Tutorial from Magnolia here is the link: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdDb-oYt18k]. 
During watching it I followed his orders. I also read the hello world tutorial in the documentation. That is, I installed magnolia with cli and created a light module and a page. Everything was created with cli so there is no way that my module could have any errors. I restarted my tomcat server and entered the admin panel. First off my module is not shown in the resource folder, neither is it shown in the page template selection menu.

What exactly could this be?

Comment: Version of magnolia, tomcat and OS on which you tried? Also please provide listing of your module (pastebin or gist or similar) and last but not least, double check that your light-module location in magnolia-properties points to place where your light-module is actually located. (if you are not sure how to check that, provide listing of magnolia.properties and full path to where your light module is.

Comment: @Jan Im using the most recent version of magnolia and tomcat on Windows 10.  The path for the resources is ${magnolia.home}/..\..\..\light-modules

Comment: Are you sure it matches the path in which your light module is created? This path pointing elsewhere than where module is is the simplest explanation of your issue. Perhaps replace that path w/ absolute path w/o any properties substitution to be sure (you might need to restart Magnolia).

Comment: @Jan Now it works thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments under the question,solution to this issue was to ensure property in magnolia.properties file denoting folder with light modules points to correct directory.
When in doubt always use absolute path.